# pulp (python) - objective function depends on the result

Tags: python, linear-programming

My objective function depends on the result of problem that i am trying to solve, is it possible to model such a problem ?

for example

```
objective = (price * is_channel_assigned[channel id])
```

the price depends on the number of channels assigned ie., 1st channel is 100, 2nd 80 .. and so on.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Sure, try making a function called `is_channel_assigned`.

Comment: Is channel_id also a decision variable, or is it an index that you are summing over?

Comment: channel_id is just an index that I am summing over.

Comment: is_channel_assigned is the LP decion variable that is either 0 or 1 depending on whether the channel is assigned or not.

Comment: when I try something like objective = price[sum(assignment[i][k] for k in nodes)] * is_channel_assigned[channel_id] i get an error " list indices must be integers, not LpAffineExpression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure make a list of the prices

and use

```
objective = (price[channel_id] * is_channel_assigned[channel_id])
```